# App catalog options for Hybrid farm configuration

Tags: sharepoint-online, app, 2019, hybrid-solution

After some research i can't find any answer regarding apps behavior in case of hybrid SP farm.

Are there any shared app catalog or some sort of syncronization between on-prem app store and O365?

Or there are complete different things and with no connection whatsoever?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is no connection what so ever. A hybrid app catalog is not a feature, which makes sense given the different targets for apps between on-prem and online (e.g. different versions of SPFx).